# Swift return error that goes against what the Apple developer site says

Tags: if-statement, return, swift2

```
func evaluateDate(nDate: Int!, rDate: Int!) -> Int{
    if(nDate < rDate) {
        return 1
    }
    if(nDate == rDate) {
        return 2
    }
    if(nDate > rDate) {
        return 3
    }
}
```

Every time I get an error that says: "Missing return in a function expected to return 'Int'"
However on the apple developer website they give an example of this doing

```
func sayHello(personName: String, alreadyGreeted: Bool) -> String {
   if alreadyGreeted {
      return sayHelloAgain(personName)
   } else {
      return sayHello(personName)

   }
}
print(sayHello("Tim", alreadyGreeted: true))
// prints "Hello again, Tim!"
```

I don't understand what's going on because also in another place I try to change the value of a variable and it doesn't recognize the variable has changed outside the if-else block, however I don't ever remember this being an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your `if statement` structure is incorrect. The compiler is complaining because the `if`'s have no `else` to fall into, subsequently the `func` is failing to return in all situations.

```
func evaluateDate(nDate: Int!, rDate: Int!) -> Int {
    if (nDate < rDate) {
        return 1
    } else if (nDate == rDate) {
        return 2
    } else {
        return 3
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Apple's example, your code will either execute the if-branch and return, or execute the else-branch and return.

In your code, there is an if and your code may return. If it doesn't return then there is another if where it may return. And another if where it may return. So what happens after the third if?

It may be obvious to you that the third if-branch will be entered and return. It isn't obvious to the compiler. It's not *that* obvious to you either, because otherwise you wouldn't have written the if at all, but just "return 3".